# How to write Data Base application in iPhone

Tags: iphone, sqlite

Hi I am create an iPhone app, which will use SQLite as database. This database is synchronized by websever by XML HTTP request. The problem is, I don't have pre-build architecture for creating database app.

Is there any tutorial which will guild me how to write Data Access Layer(DAL) or how to import SQLite file with iPhone in secured way.

I dont want to open database connection again and again, its like creating a single class which will handle all database related part.

Please suggest me.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You just described something that Apple calls Core Data.  See this link for some more details
http://cocoadevcentral.com/articles/000086.php
It does describe Core Data on the desktop but it is essentially the same.

Core Data is a pretty light wrapper for SQLite written by apple. Core data once you have your base code in place you will find it pretty easy to work with.

The other big win with Core Data is that it has a small memory foot print which is important to make sure your application performance optimal.

I would first start with some sample code, core data is going to take a few hours to get started and few days to weeks to learn but once you are past this you should find it very handy and powerful.

John.